# Why is my VS Code live sass compiler settings not compiling my scss file?

Tags: css, visual-studio-code, sass, compiler-errors

I have a lot of scss partials so I changed the settings to this: ```{
"es6-css-minify.cssPostfix": "",
"liveSassCompile.settings.autoprefix": [

```
],
"liveSassCompile.settings.formats": [
    {
        "format": "compressed",
        "extensionName": ".css",
        "savePath": "/wp-content/themes/dawn-child",
    }
],
"liveSassCompile.settings.includeItems": [ "/wp-content/themes/dawn-child/style.scss" ],
```

}

but this is not compiling scss files in the mentioned folder. I even tried to change the saved path to `dawn-child` and `dawn-child/style.css` but neither seemed to work.

I'm using the glenn marks live sass compiler. Is there anything wrong with my settings?

Answer (score 0):

Try putting a period in front of the directories:

```
"savePath": "./wp-content/themes/dawn-child",
```

And:

```
"liveSassCompile.settings.includeItems": [ "./wp-content/themes/dawn-child/style.scss" ],
```

The period indicates the current directory of the .json file you're running.